# Is there a tool that can analyse non-context-free grammars?

Tags: parsing, lexer

I know that several tools allow to define "easily" context-free grammars so as to define DSL for example.

But is there a tool that can analyse non-context-free grammars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Definite clause grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar#Non-context-free_grammars) can be used to generate parsers for non-context-free grammars. There are also several [parser generators for context-sensitive grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators#Context-sensitive), such as [LuZc](http://luzc.zohosites.com/).